# Optimal lower bound on the volume of balls under a Sobolev inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete non-compact $n$-dimensional ($n \geq 3$)
Riemannian manifold with volume element
$dv$ such that, for every smooth compactly supported function $f : M \to \mathbb {R}$,
$$
    \bigg ( \int_M |f|^{\frac {2n}{n-2}} dv\bigg)^{\frac {n-2}{n}}
    \, \leq \, C \int_M |\nabla f|^2 dv
$$
where $C >0$ is the optimal constant of this Sobolev inequality in the Euclidean case
$M = \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that
$$
    \mathrm {Vol} (B(x,r) ) \, \geq \, \mathrm{V}(r)
$$
where $B(x,r)$, $x \in M$, is a ball of radius $r >0$ in $M$ and
$\mathrm{V}(r)$ is the volume of a ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?